# How to deal with the stucked query tasks when one statement is executed by mistake in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, if a relatively large query SQL is executed by mistake in Apache IoTDB, and no data result is returned yet. This query task caused all other `select` statement to be blocked and stucked. How can I deal with this in IoTDB? (for example how can I cancel this mistaken task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `show queries` to find that mistaken query and get the queryId, then you can use `kill query <queryId>` command to manually stop this query in Apache IoTDB.